# solutions to $a+b = ab + 1$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to prove that the only solution to $$a+b = ab + 1$$ is when both $a$ and $b$ equals 1?

I've tried to find any other value for $a,b$ that satisfies the equation but I haven't found any. I haven't found any proof or pattern though, so I can't be sure.

Comment: $a=n,b=1$ works for any $n$.

Comment: ab+1-(a+b) = (a-1)(b-1) = 0. So either a-1 = 0 or b-1 = 0...

Comment: Solve the equation for $a$.  Then start over and solve the equation for $b$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** $(a - 1)(b - 1) = ab - a - b + 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Split into cases: 1) $b=1$, and 2) $b\geq2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ab+1-(a+b) = (a-1)(b-1)$$ 
so **at least one** of $a$ and $b$ has to be $1$.  Not both.

Comment: Why not both?  $2=2$.  EDIT:  n/m, I see, the "not both" should have also been removed when "**one**" was changed to "**at least one**"

Comment: @tilper OP is saying it only occurs when both are $1$, Robert is saying it actually occurs when at least one is $1$. So "not both" means "not necessarily both" here.

Comment: @arctictern, I see it now, thanks.

Comment: I meant "not both" in the sense of "it is not necessary for both to be $1$."

Answer (score 0):

Hint:..............................
$$a+b-ab-1=(a-1)(1-b)$$